# Не работает прогресс бар

Tags: javascript, html, css

Мне нужно чтобы при скролле к определенному участку сайта пользователь начинал видеть как заполняется прогрессбар,а до тех пор пока не не проскроллит к ним они находились в 0%.Я использовал `onscroll`, но у меня не заработал данный элемент.

И также мне нужно сделать так, чтобы за концом прогрессбара двигался показатель в % его заполненности как на скриншоте

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
function move(max_width) {
  var elem = document.getElementById('bar');
  var width = 1;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);

  function frame() {
    if (width >= max_width) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++;
      elem.style.width = width + '%';
    }
  }

}
```

```css
#Progress {
  position: relative;
  width: 490px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
}

#bar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="Progress" onscroll="move(95)">
  <div id="bar">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отслеживать скролл нужно у элемента который скроллишь, а не у элемента к которому скролишь.
Нужно:
 - найти координату прогрессбара
 - повесить функцию на скролл документа
 - после первого срабатывания, снять обработчик

```js
var offsetTop = $('#Progress').offset().top,
  windowHeight = $(window).height();

function move(max_width) {
  var elem = document.getElementById('bar');
  var width = 1;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);

  function frame() {
    if (width >= max_width) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++;
      elem.style.width = width + '%';
    }
  }

}
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
  var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
 
  if ((scrollTop + windowHeight) >= offsetTop) {
    move(95);
    $(document).off('scroll')
  }

})
```

```css
.test {
  height: 900px;
}

#Progress {
  position: relative;
  width: 490px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
}

#bar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test"></div>
<div id="Progress">
  <div id="bar">
  </div>
  <div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ все заработало,но только с тем элементом у которого 95%.Я хотел сделать чтобы я добавлял к функции просто количество процентов до которого она должна расширится.Можно это как то сделать чтобы я задавал в формате ` onscroll="move(75)" `

Comment: лучше так "data-scroll='95'" или "data-progress='95'" .В дату писать процент заполнения. А функцию поправить таким образом - найти все элементы с датой, запускать функцию "move" с аргументом , который берется из даты